# Customize simple symbol shape for point (sharper triangle) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, data-defined-override

I want to customize a simple symbol shape in QGIS because the basic triangle has a too large base for my purpose. I see that in simple symbol panel there is a data defined property next to the symbol selection, with a not very detailed description :
[image]
It only mentions that a string is expected but without any formatting. I couldn't find any example on this forum either.

And I don't need/want to use a SVG symbol as my wanted shape is very simple and I'm sure it is simpler done this way.

Comment: You could simply make the symbol smaller via the symbology GUI. Or does "too big" mean "I don't like the overall shape of the triangle"? Using data-defined override you may provide the names of shapes/marker symbols in this case.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong tab - go to the level above ("Symbole" in your screenshot) and just make the size smaller (not sure what it will be labelled)

Comment: I think that the answer it to use the Geometry Generator for creating a narrow triangle. Here is an example about a more demanding task https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408139/making-specified-shape-in-qgis-geometry-generator.

Comment: I edited my question. I meant, a triangle with a narrower base, so not only applying scale factor.

Comment: Resource sharing has more icons to choose from - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7N6u3VWzNpM

Comment: You can also create custom SVG Icons. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bXDoMR4ecs

Comment: OP wrote "And I don't need/want to use a SVG symbol".

Comment: The data-defined override is only for selecting one of the existing symbols by name, not to create a new symbol. I'm afraid svg symbols are your best bet OP, it can be embedded into the project at least so it almost behaves just like a simple symbol. It would be faster and less complex than a geometry generator too

Comment: Ok I understand thank you for your help everyone